# GRUB "unknown filesystem" error on second boot of each day

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I've installed a new 64GB SSD in my HP Compaq 2510p laptop. The SSD model is KingSpec KSD-ZF1.

This system is a single-boot machine running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. There are no other operating systems installed on the computer.

Using the Ubuntu installer and allowing it to automatically partition my drive, then rebooting into the newly installed system results in the `error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>` message pictured [here](http://htse.kapilarya.com/Unknown-FIle-System-GRUB-Rescue-1.jpg) (not my picture, but this is the exact error given).

I can work around this error by using the "Something Else" option in the Ubuntu installer to manually partition my drive as follows:

- 512MB ext2 partition /boot
- ~60GB ext4 partition /
- 2GB swap area

I can then boot into Ubuntu without issue. I can run the OS all day with multiple shutdowns and reboots and there are no problems.

The issue comes the day after install - on the first boot of the day, there is no problem. On the *second* boot of the day, the system returns to the `unknown filesystem` error mentioned above and must be repaired or reinstalled.

Since the error manifests itself on the second boot of each day, I suspect there may be something in `/etc/cron.daily/` which is running on the first boot of the day and breaking GRUB, but I can't see anything obvious.

Has anyone ever come across anything like this before, and if so, what was the solution? I've searched around and can't find anything, hence asking this question.

For reference, on the laptop with its previous HDD, there were no problems at all installing and running Ubuntu. The problem seems to be with Ubuntu and this specific SSD.

Thank you in advance for any assistance - usually I'm the person *helping* people with their Ubuntu issues, but this one has me stumped! If anyone would like any more information, I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: Even though it is stated that ext2, ext3 and ex4 are on high forward and backward compatibility, have you considered using ext4 for your boot partition? Or putting the question around, why did you choose ext2 over ext4 for boot partition?

Comment: have you tried boot repair? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Usually, when you choose "something else" you only need to create two partitions, one for the OS (ext4) and one for swap (linux-swap). Is this an EFI or UEFI system and is this the reason you have manually created a boot partiton? I believe there may be issues with running `sudo update-grub` when this is the case. This command is preformed by the system during certain updates; maybe this is the issue.

Comment: Also, what kind of partition scheme is used with the SSD and what was used with the HDD? If MSDOS or BIOS type was used for the HDD, you may want to verify and/or reconfigure the partition scheme of the SSD to match that of your HDD using gparted before you preform the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not only separate boot and swap partitions but also a user partition. makes it easier to back up and recover. Boot partitions need to be first on the drive. I am uncertain how SSDs handle that. Ext 2 has more support for some maintenance, diagnostics and repair than ext4. Some say 1Gb for boot partition.
You've probably been here already:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition
The UEFI and EFI question lingers as does Boot repair, which just might solve you problem. If it booted from the HDD, it is not dual boot, and if the BIOS worked for that, it is probably not UEFI, EFI, or secure boot related. Definitely try boot repair.
Good Luck